# Building a third-party library for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build

The project I'm currently working on as an intern uses a number of 3rd party libraries (libCURL, OpenSSL, and others). I've noticed that there are a number of versions of the third-party .dlls used by the project, a developer selects which one they want to use depending on what version of Visual Studio they are developing in.

My task is to upgrade two of the libraries to a newer version (libCURL and OpenSSL). One way to do this is to build the libraries from the source files and then replace the old files with the new ones. This is what I want to do, as I think I'd learn more by doing that rather than using pre-built binaries.

My question is, what special thing do I need to do during the build process to make these two libraries work with Visual Studio 20XX? Is it as simple as building the libraries using the Developer Command Promp for Visual Studio 20XX? Alternatively, if I followed the official guides to build one of the libraries for Windows x64 (which is the bitness of the Windows I'm running), presumably the resulting files wouldn't work in Visual Studio 20XX? Why not? What are these "generic-ly built" versions of a library used for?

Comment: Why don't you use the NUGET versions? That way you don't need to worry about choosing the correct version as the NUGET package manager does it for you. [OpenSSL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/openssl/) [libCURL x86](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libcurl.NET.x86/) [libCURL x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libcurl.NET.x64/)

Comment: @MercifulGiraffe That's a good suggestion, never heard of NUGET before and it looks quite handy. The OpenSSL package looks good, though the libCURL package is for an older version.

Comment: @MercifulGiraffe Also, what will happen to the old versions of libCURL and OpenSSL when I run the NUGET commands? Are they all removed for me automatically? Since the other developers didn't use NUGET to install libCURL and OpenSSL originally I wonder if there will be conflicts.